# Add a Message Bar or Info Bar to Word using interop or vsto

Tags: visual-studio, interop, vsto

I have VS 2010 and Word 2010.  In Word 2010 there is sometimes a message/warning bar that pops up under the ribbon but above the body of the document that allows the user to do an action.  It looks something like this...

[image]

Can I programmatically though VSTO or Interop create a custom bar that allows the user to click a button and then it executes some code.

If not, is there an alternative popup or dialog box that will do something like this?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

This is not provided by out-of-the box VSTO. With VSTO, you can add task panes that reside on the left or right-hand side of the Word window.

I suggest taking a look at [Add-In-Express.](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/tour.php?lp=office-task-panes) They have something called Advanced Task Panes. These panes can reside in four locations within the Word window: Top, Bottom, Left, or Right.

There is [more information about Advanced Task Panes here](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/tour.php?lp=office-task-panes).